# Google Chrome CSS главной страницы

Tags: css, google-chrome

подскажите можно ли вообще как то изменить css главной страницы в google chrome, хочу выпилить от туда поиск и логотип, и сделать как было раньше. Когда раньше пробовал делать плагин и в нем убирать, ничего не меняло.
[image: Фото]

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я знаю, расширения не могут инжектить CSS и JS в некоторый служебные страницы, например в New Tab или Chrome Web Store. Но есть возможность полностью заменить страницу New Tab на свою. Читайте тут http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override.html .

Плюс конкретно эту фичу можно отключить в about:flags, у меня она вроде бы называется "Enable Instant Extended API".